# Retrieve Witness Set from Transaction ID

Tags: transaction, public-key, signing-key-file

Is there a tool or method to get the set of witnesses (public keys) of a transaction given the transaction ID?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the **Tx file**, you can use `$ cardano-cli transaction view --tx-body-file tx.raw` to view the witness set. But, if you specifically want to extract from a given Tx ID, you can extract the **witnesses' information** through their input UTxO. The UTxO contains an address that is made up of a **hashed public key**, and from there you can list the **public key hash** needed for this transaction, also known as the **witnesses** required

Edit:
According to this [thread](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/are-transaction-witnesses-stored-on-the-blockchain?rq=1) the witness information is actually in the blockchain, **but not currently possible to extract it using db-sync**. Reference to [this specification](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/babbage.cddl) for proof that the blockchain indeed stored the witnesses' key